# What are the names of the participants of an optional binding?

Tags: swift, terminology, option-type

I know that the result of the optional binding call is called the "bound value".  But what is it bound to?  The core of what I wish to know is - besides the "bound value", what are the participants of an "optional binding", and what are they called?

Given the definition of binding as "... a mapping of one thing to another." (Wikipedia), I suspect the only other participant may be the variable or constant to which the bound value is assigned in optional binding.

But I wonder if the conditional block is also a participant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm correctly understanding your question, but..

Regardless "optional binding" or "constant/variable declaration", the right operand of `=` is called ["initializer expression"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351) in Swift.

```
if let foo = bar { ... }
|----------------------| if-statement
   |-----------|         if-condition
   |-----------|         optional-binding-list
   |-----------|         optional-binding-clause
   |-----------|         optional-binding-head
       |-|               identifiier-pattern
           |---|         initializer
             |-|         expression (called "initializer expression")
                 |-----| code-block

let foo = baz
|-----------| constant-declaration
    |-------| pattern-initializer-list
    |-------| pattern-initializer
    |-|       pattern
    |-|       identifier-pattern
        |---| initializer
          |-| expression (called "initializer expression")
```